# Views 3 Exposed Filter AJAX HTTP Error

Tags: ajax, views

Relevant modules & themes:

- zurb_foundation-7.x-4.0
- views-7.x-3.11
- jquery_update-7.x-2.6 (front-end using 1.7 and backend using 1.5)

I have an exposed views filter on the front page that is auto-submitting when the dropdown field changes. I'm using Zurb Foundation base them (v4) along with the 'custom' field style. Here's what my view and filter looks like:

[image: Exposed dropdown field with zurb custom styling]

When I choose another option, I get this:

[image: HTTP AJAX Error message]

The weird thing is that watching `views/ajax` with a debugger, Drupal generates a proper response but jQuery presents the error alert even before the debugger acknowledges the debugging request. There is no "error" showing up in the Drupal or Apache logs. Once you click "OK" the page refreshes and the block shows the proper information based on the date selected.

Comment: Is this a custom Views field handler? Error code 0 means the request was interrupted.

Comment: It is a custom field handler, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in this particular problem, what was actually happening was a double-posting of the Ajax submit handler. The first call was being interrupted and it was coming back empty. Removing the extra submit handler fixed the problem. This was directly related to the use of Zurb's custom form fields and a couple of browser issues that caused me to believe that the submit handler was not firing, but indeed it was.